# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/CalorieTracker/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

This is my application configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.spring")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

}
```

This is my application configuration initializer class.
public class AppConfigInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

```
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Class[] {AppConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new String[] {"/"};
}
```

}

This is my rest controller class.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<UserResource> createUser(@RequestBody UserResource userDetails) {
        try {
            User createdUser = userService.createUser(userDetails.toUser());
            UserResource res = new UserResourceAsm().toResource(createdUser);
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setLocation(URI.create(res.getLink("self").getHref()));
            return new ResponseEntity<UserResource>(res, headers,  HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (UserExistsException e) {
            throw new ConflictException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

In the console I am getting this warning

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/CalorieTracker/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

I believe because of this warning when I tried to call my rest api "http://localhost:8080/CalorieTracker/user", I am getting status 404.

Can anyone help what is wrong while configuring the program?

Comment: add `caloieTracker` in mapping as `@requestMapping(value="CalorieTracker",method...)` and remove mapping for `user` since you have not attached and returned page with it

Comment: No, that will not work. Can you tell me why I am getting that warning "No mapping found for HTTP request" ?

Comment: read this for reference (http://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping)

Comment: just try to replace RestController with @Controller.

Comment: @georgesvanhoutte I am not sure about `springrest` but I think he might need `RestController`

Comment: Actually @RestController should work. The only problem now I am facing is the warning of main project name in the url "/CalorieTracker/". I have not defined it any where in the project. But how does this appeared in warning? Or I need to configure main project name in configuration. 
I have just defined "/" for servlet mapping.

Comment: can you post full stacktrace?

Comment: WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/CalorieTracker/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Only this is warning I am getting.

Comment: did you studied the link i posted?

Comment: and I cannot see any mapping attached to `CalorieTracker`

Comment: This is because I do not need mapping for "CalorieTracker". "CalorieTracker" is the main project name. And I am getting warning for the mapping related to that name.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController
```

to

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UserController
```